# scss cannot use builtin function (map.get)

Tags: css, sass

`list.nth` is not causing errors but `map.set` is, no idea why (new to sass).

```
@use "sass:map";
@use "sass:list";

$fontSizes: (200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900);
@function createFontSizes($baseFontSize, $multiplier) {
    $temp: ();
    @for $i from 1 through length($fontSizes) {
        $current: list.nth($fontSizes, $i);
        map.set($temp, $current, $baseFontSize * $multiplier * $i);
    };

    @return $temp;
}
```

Error

```
Error: expected "$".
   ╷
10 │         map.set($temp, $current, $baseFontSize * $multiplier * $i);
   │             ^
   ╵
```

Comment: Are you using Dart Sass to compile with? If you arnt sure, try map-set with the hyphen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@use "sass:map";
@use "sass:list";

$fontSizes: (200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900);
@function createFontSizes($baseFontSize, $multiplier) {
    $temp: ();
    @for $i from 1 through length($fontSizes) {
        $current: list.nth($fontSizes, $i);

        // should assign to the variable
        $temp: map.set($temp, $current, $baseFontSize * $multiplier * $i);
    };

    @return $temp;
}
```